# delphi Debugging only my source

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop the debugger from stepping into Delphi-supplied units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074306/how-do-i-stop-the-debugger-from-stepping-into-delphi-supplied-units)

I have a following problem: when I am running application, the debugger gets into delphi's VCL source. I want it to run just through code I wrote.

Example:

```
temp := nil;
// Here is breakpoint, after that I wanna go line-by-line, so I'm hitting F7
while (Head <> nil) do begin
   if (Head^.Next = nil) then break;
   Temp := Head^.Next;
   dispose(Head); // <- here debugger goes into [*]
end;
if (Temp <> nil) then dispose(Temp);
```

---

```
// [*]
procedure _Dispose(P: Pointer; TypeInfo: Pointer);
{$IFDEF PUREPASCAL}
begin
  _Finalize(P, TypeInfo);
  FreeMem(P);
end;
{$ELSE}
asm
        { ->    EAX     Pointer to object to be disposed        }
        {       EDX     Pointer to type info                    }

{$IFDEF ALIGN_STACK}
        SUB     ESP, 8
{$ENDIF ALIGN_STACK}
        PUSH    EAX
        CALL    _Finalize
        POP     EAX
{$IFDEF ALIGN_STACK}
        SUB     ESP, 4
{$ENDIF ALIGN_STACK}
        CALL    _FreeMem
{$IFDEF ALIGN_STACK}
        ADD     ESP, 12
{$ENDIF ALIGN_STACK}
end;
{$ENDIF !PUREPASCAL}
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768622/is-there-a-way-to-trace-through-only-project-source-in-delphi), and it haven't helped me. How to exclude delphi sources, to do debugging only my code?

Comment: Is "Use debug .dcus" disabled in the project Options?

Comment: Looks like you are right. I was looking for it, but I couldn't find

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look in the `Project->Options` menu item.  Go to Compiler Options and there should be a setting that says "Use Debug DCUs".  Make sure it's not checked, and you should stop tracing into standard library sources.